# httpでJSONデータを返すRustプログラムのエラーハンドリング

Tags: json, http, rust

習作として、「URLでidとnameを指定して、それをJSON形式に変換し返却する」というプログラムを書いています。
以下のようにプログラムを書いたのですが、index関数のResult部分でエラーが発生し、コンパイルできません。
「Serializeを実装していない」というエラーハンドリングに関する文法エラーなのですが、ここからどう修正してよいのかわかりません。
どこが問題で何をするとよいのか教えていただけると嬉しいです。
↓main.rs

```
use actix_web::{get, web, App, HttpResponse, HttpServer, Responder, Result};
use serde::{Deserialize, Serialize};

#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize)]
struct NameId{
    name: String,
    id: u32,
}

#[get("/{id}/{name}/index.html")]
async fn index(name_id: web::Path<NameId>) ->Result<impl Responder> {
    Ok(web::Json(name_id))
}

#[actix_web::main]
async fn main() -> std::io::Result<()> {
    HttpServer::new(|| App::new().service(index))
        .bind("127.0.0.1:8080")?
        .run()
        .await
}
```

↓Cargo.toml

```
[package]
name = "test"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

# See more keys and their definitions at https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html

[dependencies]
actix-web = "4.0.1"
serde = {version = "1.0.136", features = ["derive"]}
serde_json = "1.0.79"
```

追記
↓エラー出力

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `actix_web::web::Path<NameId>: _::_serde::Serialize` is not satisfied
  --> src\main.rs:15:46
   |
15 | async fn index(name_id: web::Path<NameId>) ->Result<impl Responder> {
   |                                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `_::_serde::Serialize` is not implemented for `actix_web::web::Path<NameId>`
   |
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `Responder` for `Json<actix_web::web::Path<NameId>>`       

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0277`.
```

Comment: 可能でしたらエラーメッセージを添付してください

Comment: こめんとありがとうございます
エラーメッセージを追記しました

Answer (score 2, accepted):

結論から言うと、以下の行を

```rust
    Ok(web::Json(name_id))
```

以下のように変更するとエラーが解消します。

```rust
    Ok(web::Json(name_id.into_inner()))
```

**説明**

元のコードでは`name_id`の値を`web::Json`構造体に入れていますが、`name_id`引数の型である`Path<NameId>`型は`Serialize`を実装していません。そのために以下のエラーになっています。

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `actix_web::web::Path<NameId>: _::_serde::Serialize` is not satisfied
```

`name_id.into_inner()`とすると、`Path<NameId>`型の値の中にある`NameId`型の値が取り出せます。`NameId`型は`#[derive(Serialize, ...)]`により`Serialize`を実装していますのでエラーが解消するわけです。